# WideVineCDM not working or Ruffle Flash emulator

Tags: flash, widevine, ruffle

my videos on netflix and udemy no longer play on chrome or firefox. I get the message wideVineCdm has crashed.

I've tried to use the plugin ruffle flash emulator for both Chrome and Firefox to solve the problem but that's not made any difference. Checked the settings... everything activated and on...

I'm on mac 10.9.5, is it too old for this ruffle plugin?

Any suggestions to solve this would be appreciated

Comment: Some searching tells me Widevine CDM is not Flash-based but HTML5-based. If that's the case, then Ruffle will not be of any use here. I don't know anything about Widevine CDM, though. I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to get help with this issue, but I'm not sure where's the best place to ask either. Disclaimer: I did not vote on your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am a total loss then. Suddenly after years working fine the videos don't play on some sites for FF and Chrome. I noticed WideVine updated few days when it stopped working. Safari works but that's using silverlight but I prefer the other browsers. I'm waiting for an external hardrive so I can upgrade it to a newer operating system...  i'm not sure what else to do. If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I click on the 'WideVine has crashed' link from netflix or udemy it takes me to a mozilla support page with it highlighted in a box at the top 'End of Flash Support: Like other browsers and Adobe, firefox ended flash support at the end of 2020. '

Comment: Huh, interesting. That seems to contradict the Widevine documentation I read. Not sure if Moz documentation is in the right or wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post an update for anyone else that stumbles upon this problem. I had been working on a wordpress site locally using local by flywheel with no problems. Not long before my udemy videos stopped playing my site wouldn't load up locally... anyway I removed and did a fresh reinstall of local by flywheel and now my videos are working fine on udemy and netflix.... as well as my site loading locally. I have no idea how or why.... but maybe this might be of help to somebody else.